# Jquery apending <tr> to table closing the <tr> tag unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery `append` method to add `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>`. I have to get the following table structure

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
       <div>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="33%"></td>
                      <td width="4%">:</td>
                      <td width="63%"></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
      </td> 
      <td>
       <div>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="33%"></td>
                      <td width="4%">:</td>
                      <td width="63%"></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
      </td> 
      <td>
       <div>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="33%"></td>
                      <td width="4%">:</td>
                      <td width="63%"></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
      </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
       <div>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="33%"></td>
                      <td width="4%">:</td>
                      <td width="63%"></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
      </td> 
      <td>
       <div>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="33%"></td>
                      <td width="4%">:</td>
                      <td width="63%"></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
      </td> 
      <td>
       <div>
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td width="33%"></td>
                      <td width="4%">:</td>
                      <td width="63%"></td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
         </div>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to add a class to `<tr>` and inside its contents dynamically. And i am doing it via jquery append method.
But the problem is that when appending the `<tr>` after appending the first `<td>` the `<tr>` is getting closed. I need to insert three `<td>` inside `<tr>` and close that. So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: You can only `.append()` complete nodes, not partial tags. However, there's no reason you can't append the table cells to the table row one at a time.

Comment: We need to see your jQuery code to help you

Comment: That said, your mess of nested tables is probably unnecessary and certainly outdated. Consider using fixed-width spans with `display: inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.append()` you're not adding tags, you're adding DOM objects. What you want to do is then append the `<td>`s to the newly created `<tr>`, like so:

```
var tr = $('<tr>');

// Add the row to the table
$('table tbody').append(tr);

// Add cells to the new row
tr.append('<td>1</td>');
tr.append('<td>2</td>');
tr.append('<td>3</td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#tb tbody tr').first().append(' <td>  add td  </td>'); 

    $('#tb tbody').append('<tr><td>  add tr  </td></tr>');
```